# Multiple Jbutton and ActionListener using inner class

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, paintcomponent

There are two buttons for this app. One is for randomly changing color when clicked and the other is for changing a label in the app.

The problem is although I've write sepreate `ActionListener` classes and registered them with correspondence methods respectively.

Every time I click the "change label" button, the color changes as well. What's going on here?

```
package my;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class SimpleGui3C {

        JFrame frame;
        JLabel label;

        public static void main(String[] args){
            SimpleGui3C gui = new SimpleGui3C();
            gui.go();
        }

        public void go(){
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JButton labelButton = new JButton("Change Label");
            labelButton.addActionListener(new LabelListener());

            JButton colorButton = new JButton("Change Circle");
            colorButton.addActionListener(new ColorListener());

            label = new JLabel("I'm a label");

            MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();

            frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,colorButton);
            frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,drawPanel);
            frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, labelButton);
            frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, label);

            frame.setSize(300,300);
            frame.setVisible(true);


        }

        class LabelListener implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event1) {
                ArrayList<String> labelContent = new ArrayList<String>();
                labelContent.add("Ouch!");
                labelContent.add("Damn!");
                labelContent.add("Holy shit!");
                labelContent.add("WTF?!");
                labelContent.add("Stop it!");
                labelContent.trimToSize();

                int i = (int)(Math.random()*5);
                String a = (String)labelContent.get(i);
                label.setText(a);
            }
        }

        class ColorListener implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event2) {
                frame.repaint();
            }
        }
    }

            package my;
            import java.awt.*;
            import javax.swing.*;

            public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel{
                /**
                 * 
                 */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

                    int red = (int)(Math.random()*255);
                    int blue = (int)(Math.random()*255);
                    int green = (int)(Math.random()*255);
                    Color startColor = new Color(red,blue,green);

                    red = (int)(Math.random()*255);
                    blue = (int)(Math.random()*255);
                    green = (int)(Math.random()*255);
                    Color endColor = new Color(red,blue,green);

                    int startPositionX = (int)(Math.random()*70);
                    int startPositionY = (int)(Math.random()*70);

                    int endPositionX = (int)(Math.random()*150);
                    int endPositionY = (int)(Math.random()*150);

                    GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(startPositionX,startPositionY,startColor,endPositionX,endPositionY,endColor);
                    g2d.setPaint(gradient);
                    g2d.fillOval(20,60,100,100);

                }
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be helpful if you could reduce the size of your code example. For example, much of the label content is irrelevant and offensive (to some).

Comment: just for future reference, in your LabelListener, I don't think you mean `int i = (int)(Math.random()*5);` If you use the modulus (`%`) function, it will only return 0-[number modding by]. Also, in your case it might be better to use `labelContent.size()` instead of `5` that way you can add/subtract options without breaking your code. So what I'm suggesting all in all is: `int i = (int)(Math.random() % labelContent.size());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you click `labelButton` it is firing a repaint event for `MyDrawPanel`.

This causes the color to be randomly generated again, changing the color of `MyDrawPanel`.

I suggest fixing this by calling a method from ColorListener on MyDrawPanel which changes its color. This will keep the panel from changing color every repaint.

And here's precisely how to do it:

```
class ColorListener implements ActionListener{
    MyDrawPanel colorPanel;
    public ColorListener(MyDrawPanel panel){
        this.colorPanel = panel;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event2) {
        colorPanel.generateRandomColor();
        frame.repaint();
    }
}

public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel{
    GradientPaint gradient;
    public MyDrawPanel(){ 
        generateRandomColor();
    }
    public void generateRandomColor(){
        int red = (int)(Math.random()*255);
        int blue = (int)(Math.random()*255);
        int green = (int)(Math.random()*255);
        Color startColor = new Color(red,blue,green);

        red = (int)(Math.random()*255);
        blue = (int)(Math.random()*255);
        green = (int)(Math.random()*255);
        Color endColor = new Color(red,blue,green);

        int startPositionX = (int)(Math.random()*70);
        int startPositionY = (int)(Math.random()*70);

        int endPositionX = (int)(Math.random()*150);
        int endPositionY = (int)(Math.random()*150);

        gradient = new GradientPaint(startPositionX,startPositionY,
            startColor, endPositionX,endPositionY,endColor);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks indeed! But is there any solution that using inner class to separate the action?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably when you change label a repaint() is called and MyDrawPanel.paintComponent() is called and frame repainted with random color.
Better implementation can be:

```
class SimpleGui3C {
  Color startColor;
  Color endColor;

  ColorListener() {
    startColor = <code to generate a random color>;
    endColor = <code to generate a random color>;
    repaint();
  }
}
```

and in 
`MyDrawPanel.paintComponent()` use `startColor` and `endColor` generated by listener; remember to init Color variables to avoid NPE!